# Is there a way to define schema constraints on TinkerGraph?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I wonder if it is possible to define in-memory schema contraints for in-memory TinkerGraph using TinkerPop 3. So if something is not allowed it will throw Exceptions like DSE Graph and Titan are doing. Right now the schema is defined by the insertions so it would be nice if it is possible to have an optional schema for TinkerGraph

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TinkerGraph is meant to be a simple in-memory graph database. It therefore doesn't support the notion of a schema, transactions, or other more heavy-weight features. In the past, the TinkerPop Community has considered generalizing its APIs to support the schema concept, but like indices, the features tend to be overly disparate and difficult to generalize without compromising capabilities to the point where the feature isn't useful. As such, it doesn't seem as though this kind of feature will come about without some newer thinking on the issue.